# Is it possible to make a Dutch baby, or similar, without an oven?

Tags: pancakes, dutch-oven

I find myself temporarily without an oven, but am really craving a [Dutch baby](https://www.thekitchn.com/how-to-make-a-dutch-baby-pancake-227629).  Since a Dutch baby is cooked in a very hot oven, clearly I can't make a normal one.  But is there any version of one, or a similar "puff" pancake, that can be made entirely on the stovetop?

I've found some recipes for making one in a [Dutch oven](https://www.sunset.com/recipe/raspberry-double-dutch-baby), which I happen to have handy, but those all require hot coals to stack top and bottom heat.  I just have an electric stovetop.

I'm looking here for "one big pancake" that fills the pan and puffs up a lot, instead of regular small flat pancakes.  Is it in any way possible to make such a thing using only bottom heat?

Comment: When a Dutch man and a Dutch woman love each other very much, they share a *special* kind of hug…

Comment: I don't know about only bottom heat, but do you have a cast iron pan you could preheat and use in place of the normal lid?

Comment: The link says it's done in a skillet.  Perhaps you could use a pan on the stove-top.   Japanese-style fluffy pancakes (using whipped egg whites) might be an OK substitute.  Perhaps: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qarg7peLYr4  They sounds similar to the super-fluffy pancake in the link.

Comment: Kingsley: that sounds like an answer, post it?

Comment: Dutch babies are more popover like than soufflé like.  If I were to try it, I’d probably use a well heated cast iron dutch oven, with drippings or fat, add the batter, put the lid on but drop the heat so you don’t scorch the bottom.  And make sure your batter is warmed to room temperature before making.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had moderate success with a two Dutch baby methods on stovetop.

In the first, I use a pre-heated cast iron pan as a salamander/lid on top of the pan I'm cooking the Dutch baby in. If you can get your second skillet hot enough and introduce a bit of steam into the vessel before you seal it, this makes a pretty serviceable Dutch baby. The top won't brown, and the bottom will probably dry out while you wait for the rest to cook, but it works.

In the second method, I flip the Dutch baby Spanish omelette style after it's had a chance to rise and the bottom is fully cooked (invert pancake onto a plate-> slide pancake raw side down back into pan). The result doesn't look so much like a Dutch baby, but it does more or less have the same internal structure as a Dutch baby that's been allowed to cool.

Comment: thanks for the delayed answer!  I don't know when I'll get a chance to try it, but I'll report back if I do

Answer (score -1):

Maybe use a BBQ, probably propane would be preferred. I made a pie in a BBQ once. Worked pretty well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately, at the time, I literally only had the electric cooktop: no oven, no grill, no outdoor area to dig a firepit.